# how to keep the div tag in the center of the background image and should be responsive

Tags: html, css

How can I keep this `div` in the centre on the background image?

```css
.imagesearch {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/500x150");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.input-group {
  position: absolute;
}
.title {
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
.search {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagesearch col-md-12">
  <div class="input-group ">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Keyword" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2">
    <select name="title" class="title">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Location:</option>
      <option value="animals">Pune</option>
      <option value="birds">Mumbai</option>
      <option value="plants">Delhi</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button class="search">SEARCH</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: used to background-position : top center;

Comment: add you html too or link to jsfidlle or something

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v242utt2/       I want to bring the div tag in the centre of the background image and it should be responsive means as i increase the size of the browser the div tag should be in the centre.

Comment: Rohit Azad it is not working

Comment: @Harry are you using bootstrap ?

Comment: yes i am using @robo dev

Comment: @Harry please check my answer. its responsive too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.imagesearch {
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQGaONLkZH9xSY96QkElKMO0vduB0fw_JaPoLLh0km5Ooe8ulo");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
.imagesearch .input-group {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px
}
.title {
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
.search {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .imagesearch {
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 33%;
  }
  div.imagesearch div.input-group{
    width: 100%;
  }
  .dropdown {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 1em 0 0;
  }
  .search {
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="imagesearch col-md-12">
  <div class="input-group ">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Keyword" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2">
    <select name="title" class="title">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Location:</option>
      <option value="animals">Pune</option>
      <option value="birds">Mumbai</option>
      <option value="plants">Delhi</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button class="search">SEARCH</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or change (imagesearch) the background-size: 100% to background-size:cover and height to 100%

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7r4qkqjx/  See i have attached all the codes and it is not working when i use background-size:cover and height 100%. The image disapppears when i resize window

Comment: @ ronald Zwiers the above css of yours is also not working the image disappears when i resize the window

Comment: Try adding:html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

Comment: Edit the above code again. Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Yes it is working bt the background image is getting smaller on the desktop view.

Comment: You could add height: 40%; to your @media all and (max-width : 768px); and  .imagesearch height: 100%; See edit version above

Comment: one prob i m getting is that when i resize the window the width of the text box is not getting responsive at the end.

Comment: change in your @media: .imagesearch.input-group into div.imagesearch div.input-group and maybe remove the top 300px;

Comment: All the things worked fine thax a lot dude...nw what i want to do is that convert my full code into php using classes and bring all my my data from mysql database using the connection pool. And i am new to the php and the the mysql database.It will be great if u could provide me some tutorials related to these.

Comment: ya ohk how cn i convert it?

Comment: Than you need to create a php framework good starting point:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-php5-framework-part-1--net-520 or http://laravel.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center certain object maybe the easiest way to accomplish this is the following design:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div.parent{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:blue;
}

div.parent div.child{
   position:absolute;
   margin:auto;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Remember that the child element must have a width and height.

Comment: thank you for your reply @Ronald Zwiers but as soon as i resize my window it disappears.It should also b responsive. So when i see in a mobile view, Landscape or anything it should be in the centre on the top of the backgroung image.

Comment: Edited the above code should always centre your object now.. Give it a try

Comment: @ ronald Zwiers  ya great its working bt my background size is 100% so when i resize it the div remains in the centre but it is not on the image it is going down when i resize it

Comment: Did you give your parent class (imagesearch) the position:relative?

Comment: Try to give this class a position relative. Now the absolute object will only be inside its relative parent.

Comment: Also i see that you use 500px for your imagesearch class. Try to use percentage e.g 20%

Comment: Still it is going down and i have changed the child width to 400px bcoz the size of the text box is very small. And i am using media queires so i also have to change i media queries??

Comment: Insert:html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding what you want is to position "*.input-group*" div to center, if it is correct you can do it as follows.

**HTML**

```
<div class="imagesearch col-md-12">
    <div class="input-group ">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Keyword" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2">
        <!-- </div> -->
        <!-- dropdown on image -->
        <!-- <div class="dropdown"> -->
        <select name="title" class="title">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Location:</option>
            <option value="animals">Pune</option>
            <option value="birds">Mumbai</option>
            <option value="plants">Delhi</option>
        </select>
        </br>
        <!-- </div> -->
        <button class="search">SEARCH</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.imagesearch {
    background-image:url("slide.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 500px;
    background-size: 100%;
}
.input-group {
    position: absolute;
    margin:auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.title {
    margin-top: 10px;
    height:30px;
    width: 100%;
}
.search {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

just set left and right of the absolute positioned div to 0, as well as set its margin to auto.

I have edited your fiddle, and is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v242utt2/1/)

Comment: dev  ya i want to centre the .input group on the backgroung url image but the div is on the left side. Plz visit these site gorenty.com and see the image on the home page.I want to do exactly the same.

Comment: you want both inputs aligned inline ?

Comment: can you check the fiddle that I have posted with my answer. in that the input-group class is aligned center of the screen.

Comment: no thats ok event if it comes one below the another. Bt it should be in the centre and should be responsive

Comment: ya i have seen and tried it but it is coming on the left

Comment: please check the link,http://postimg.org/image/vgjkylm99/ . contains the screenshot

Comment: have you hosted the website somewhere ? if you can share the link, it would be great

Comment: @Harry for absolute positioned div we can align it in to center as I have done above. I think your code should be different from pasted in question. I think some where you have specified a float:left property. please check it carefully. or paste your full code were we can see

Answer (score 0):

To centre things horizontally and vertically, the best method is to use a tabular format and use `vertical-align:middle;` and `text-align:center;`. You then simply set the element you want everything centred in to `display:table-cell` and then wrap that in an element that is set to `display:table`.

Here's the code, I centred the image instead of stretching it to make it more obvious that it's working:

```css
.table-container {
  display:table;  
  width:100%;
  height: 500px;
}
.imagesearch {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/450x450");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.title {
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
.search {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <div class="imagesearch col-md-12">
    <div class="input-group ">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Keyword" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2">
      <select name="title" class="title">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Location:</option>
        <option value="animals">Pune</option>
        <option value="birds">Mumbai</option>
        <option value="plants">Delhi</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <button class="search">SEARCH</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```